# Fastest-path algorithm

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

I'm currently implementing a navigation system for routing through Europe. So far, I have shortest path implemented (Dijkstra and A*). It was the easy part, now I need some algorithm for fastest path. It has to be fast and reliable.

I know it can be done just by assigning values to a road quality (for example 1 highway, 2 main road ...), then multiply these values with route costs and finaly use Dijkstra or A*, but it's not sophisticated enough.

I'm searching for more accurate algorithm. The map itself contains all kinds of data, like road quality, speed limits, traffic lights positions etc., and I want to use it.

Are there any good algorithms for this? Or at least a good modification of A*?

Comment: A "fastest" path algorithm is just a shortest path algorithm where the edge weights are weighted travel time instead of distance.  A* is still going to be your best bet, you're just going to have to come up with a good way to estimate the weights based on the available data (and come up with a heuristic).

Comment: Why can't you just factor everything in when calculating the edge costs (like you suggest for road quality)?

Comment: I thought there have to be better approach. But if everyone suggests modified A* is the best solution, then I'll be good with it.

Comment: Nothing in A* dictates what you should pick as edge-weight. So in a sense it's still not a modified version of A*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your implementation for shortest path you chose distance as weight for an edge.

Now if you want to find the fastest path, you simply **pick expected travel time as weight for the edges instead**. Similarly, if you want the most reliable path, you pick some measurement of "reliability" as weight for the edges.

A* (although not always optimal, as it relies on a heuristics function) is probably your best option for this type of application. If your A* is not accurate enough, I suggest you either go for Dijkstras or spend some time on tweaking and improving your heuristics function.

Comment: A* is always optimal, as long as it's heuristic is admissible, at least by the computer-science definition of "optimal"

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure that I get what admissible means in this context. However, I doubt that it's possible to have such heuristic function for a graph with arbitrary edge-weights.

Comment: You certainly can - admissible functions for those cases are easy to find (for example for real distance - you just measure the aerial line (is that how you call it?))

Comment: Thanks for answers. And is it really ok to mix different weights with simple heuristic like euclidean distance? I thought I'd need to adjust heuristic to weightening at least.

Comment: Your heuristic function should as accurately as possible estimate the remaining distance/travel time/what not.

Comment: A few years late: an admissible heuristic is one that is proven never to underestimate the distance. As @OrenA mentionned, the beeline is admissible for finding the shortest path between two points with known coordinated.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by 'fastest' path. If you knew the average speed you could travel on on each segment of the road, then you could just convert your graph so the edges contain "time taken to travel" instead of "distance". Then you can do a shortest-path algorithm over the new graph.

It seems like you mentioned that's not good enough, though. I think the problem is that you have to define what 'fastest' means. How does road quality affect speed? What about traffic lights? These are all variables you have to find a way to account for. If you as a human don't know the metric you'll be using, it'll be hard to get the computer to do it.